# RuntimeBinderException 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' in MVC code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In the line of code:

```
<div class="col-md-11 bky-points-summary-body-content">
    @Html.Raw(model.GetRawValue("body").ToString().Replace("[XXX]", (200 - ViewBag.CurrentBalance).ToString()))
</div>
```

I am getting the exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a null reference'

I've tried to re-arrange the code a little by changing the places of the reference to the ViewBag, etc. but nothing seems to help.

Comment: almost certainly the viewbag value isn't set, I would guess

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint on that line in the cshtml?

Comment: `ViewBag.CurrentBalance` seems has null value. Try `ViewBag.CurrentBalance ?? 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RuntimeBinderException` often occurs when `ViewBag` property has null value, in this case `ViewBag.CurrentBalance` has null value (and you cannot subtract integer value with null).

Try using null coalescing operator for `ViewBag.CurrentBalance` with a default value when `ViewBag.CurrentBalance` is null, or assign it from controller action:

```
@Html.Raw(model.GetRawValue("body").ToString().Replace("[XXX]", 
         (200 - (ViewBag.CurrentBalance ?? 0)).ToString()))
```

Note that [operator precendence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index) for null-coalescing operator (`??`) is lower than subtraction operator (`-`), hence you should use parenthesis/brackets around null-coalescing operator for higher priority.